# Is it possible to retrieve all unanswered email?

Tags: email, crm, gmail-api

My use case is that I sometimes fail to reply to messages say sent to me via sales@example.com. Hence dropping valuable business development!

I need a way to create a filter to show all the messages missing replies.

I can't seem do this from within Gmail's filter dialog. :(

[image: Gmail's filter creation dialog]

I have a bit of a stare at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list aka the new Gmail API and I don't see a way of doing this.

Do you have any ideas? Should I be using IMAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you stared at the right place. you can use the gmail-api to fetch all threads:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?q=to:sales@example.com`

then you'll have to fetch each thread:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/<thread-id>?fields=messages`
now this will get you the list of messages. if the size is 1, then it's unanswered.

Comment: This looks right, but I'm a bit worried this is fairly cumbersome. It's no easier than IMAP IIUC with `UID THREAD references UTF-8 all`.

Comment: you're right. However Google states that gmail-api is faster than imap. i didn't notice any difference though.